# Why is there no pulse-audio sink created after connection to bluetooth device

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, gdm, bluez

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

There is no pulse-audio sink created after connection to bluetooth device :

Here's what I do :

```bash
$ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:04 sebastien-B206 [default]
[NEW] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 PROZOR RX5.0
[bluetooth]# pair 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 
Attempting to pair with 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Modalias: bluetooth:v05D6p000Ad0240
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Trusted: yes
Changing 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 
Attempting to connect to 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[PROZOR RX5.0]# info
Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
    Name: PROZOR RX5.0
    Alias: PROZOR RX5.0
    Class: 0x340404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v05D6p000Ad0240
```

As you can see below, no new pulse-audio sink is created :

```bash
$ pactl list sinks short 
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.1.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
$ pactl list sinks short | grep bluez_sink
$
```

I restarted the `bluetooth.service` and also restarted `pulseaudio` but it didn't solve the pb.

Why is there no pulse-audio sink created ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to disable `pulseaudio` in GDM because  `pulseaudio` instance of GDM was "stealing" the bluetooth sink from `$USER`.

So here's what I did thanks to [Gnome_with_GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Gnome_with_GDM) :

```bash
$ ps -fC pulseaudio
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
gdm       1858     1  0 14:27 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
sebasti+  3263     1  2 14:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
$ gdm_home=$(grep gdm /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6)
$ sudo -u gdm mkdir -pv $gdm_home/.config/pulse/ $gdm_home/.config/systemd/user/
$ sudo test ! -s $gdm_home/.config/pulse/client.conf && printf "autospawn = no\ndaemon-binary = /bin/true\n" | sudo -u gdm tee $gdm_home/.config/pulse/client.conf
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
$ sudo -u gdm ln -vs /dev/null $gdm_home/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket
'/var/lib/gdm3/.config/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket' -> '/dev/null'
$ sudo reboot
$ ps -fC pulseaudio
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
sebasti+  3024     1  0 15:03 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
$ pactl list modules short | grep blue
8   module-bluetooth-policy
9   module-bluetooth-discover
10  module-bluez5-discover
31  module-bluez5-device    path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_97_40_B1_EF_BD_54
$ { echo disconnect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54;sleep 2;echo connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54;sleep 2; } | bluetoothctl 2>/dev/null | egrep -i "(dis)?connect(ion|ed)?|successful"
[bluetooth]# disconnect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Attempting to disconnect from 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Successful disconnected
[bluetooth]# connect 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
Attempting to connect to 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54
[CHG] Device 97:40:B1:EF:BD:54 Connected: yes
Connection successful
$ pactl list sinks short | grep bluez_sink
4   bluez_sink.97_40_B1_EF_BD_54    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
$ pactl list sink-inputs short
0   0   8   protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 44100Hz
$ pactl move-sink-input 0 4
$
```